# Editing the elements produced in a foreach loop

Tags: php, kohana

I'm using a plugin for my website which is built on a PHP based CMS that uses Kohana.

The plugin generates a new drop down menu. I believe that the actual menu is generated by the script "sharing_bar.php. This script is below. I believe the foreach function at the bottom is where I need to edit.

I'd like to do two things:

1. Hide the first line item of the menu
2. Change the text in the second item of the menu. Currently the text generated is dynamic via a function.

The website in question is here: http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr
The box I'd like to change is to the right and is called "site filter" with 3 items:

- All
- Crowdsourced Architectural Salvage
- Archives

I'd like to change this to display two items:

- All Sites: Hidden
- Crowdsourced Architectural Salvage > "Current"
- Archives > No change

At the end of the foreach function is a div "site_name". The existing list above are site names (Crowdsourced Architectural Salvage & Archives). The function is pulling in their names dynamically. I need to "hard edit" the names here and I really don't know how to.

```
<div class="cat-filters clearingfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <strong><?php echo Kohana::lang('sharing_two.site_filter');?>
        <span>[<a href="javascript:toggleLayer('sharing_switch_link','sharing_switch')" id="sharing_switch_link">
            <?php echo Kohana::lang('ui_main.hide'); ?></a>]
        </span>
    </strong>
</div>

<ul id="sharing_switch" class="category-filters">
    <li><a href="#" id="share_all" <?php if (Kohana::config('sharing_two.default_sharing_filter') == 'all') echo' class="active"'; ?>>
        <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#<?php echo Kohana::config('settings.default_map_all'); ?>"></div>
        <div><?php echo Kohana::lang('sharing_two.all_sites') ?></div>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="share_main"<?php if (Kohana::config('sharing_two.default_sharing_filter') == 'main') echo' class="active"'; ?>>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#<?php echo Kohana::config('settings.default_map_all'); ?>"></div>
                <div><?php echo Kohana::config('settings.site_name') ?></div>
    </a></li>
    <?php
        foreach ($sites as $site)
        {
            $class = (Kohana::config('sharing_two.default_sharing_filter') == $site->id) ? "active" : '';
            echo '<li><a href="#" id="share_'. $site->id .'" class="'.$class.'"><div class="swatch" style="background-color:#'.$site->site_color.'"></div><div>'.$site->site_name.'</div></a></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your post seems really long-winded for what you apparently want to do. Can't you just keep an index (or use a `for` loop that scopes its own index) and `if (i == 0) ...` etc?

Comment: What plugin are you using. Please post an URL.

Comment: isn't the `crowdsourced ..` already the current?

Comment: @tim the plugin is at this link. It's purpose is to share content between two sites that use the same platform. I'm "hacking it" in that I'm using it to store old content https://github.com/rjmackay/Ushahidi-plugin-sharing_two

Comment: @bansi yes that's correct. All I'd like to do is change the name of "crowdsourced..." to "Current" in that box

Comment: just remove the first `<li>... </li>` inside the `<ul>`

Comment: and in the second `<li>` change `<?php echo Kohana::config('settings.site_name') ?>` to `Current`. i think that is what you want.

Comment: @DougFirr does the plugin have a settings page?

Comment: @bansi thanks a lot. I think I was overcomplicating it because I'm nervous of Kohana. Fixed now

Comment: @tim on the back end it does but since it's for an older version of the platform the back end (non developer) functionality does not work. Think I've got it fixed now though. Thanks all

Comment: I can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first `<li>` to remove 'All'. For the second `<li>` you have to add another item `current` to settings and use that. check http://docs.kohanaphp.com/core/kohana#methods_config for more details on config.

```
<ul id="sharing_switch" class="category-filters">
    <li><a href="#" id="share_main"<?php if (Kohana::config('sharing_two.default_sharing_filter') == 'main') echo' class="active"'; ?>>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#<?php echo Kohana::config('settings.default_map_all'); ?>"></div>
                <div><?php echo Kohana::config('settings.current') ?></div>
    </a></li>
    <?php
        foreach ($sites as $site)
        {
            $class = (Kohana::config('sharing_two.default_sharing_filter') == $site->id) ? "active" : '';
            echo '<li><a href="#" id="share_'. $site->id .'" class="'.$class.'"><div class="swatch" style="background-color:#'.$site->site_color.'"></div><div>'.$site->site_name.'</div></a></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you  can just replace `<?php echo Kohana::config('settings.site_name') ?>` with `Current` . But this is not a good practice.